# Magento - Forcing a form field to send upper case values to database

Tags: php

We want to force registration form fields input to be all in uppercase and I tried this code `<?php @$_REQUEST['firstname'] = strtoupper(@$_REQUEST['firstname']); ?>` but it doesn't help. Am I missing our something?

```
<div class="field name-firstname">
<?php @$_REQUEST['firstname'] = strtoupper(@$_REQUEST['firstname']); ?>    
    <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing strtoupper on the form field value, not the actual value being sent to your action script, which handles the form processing. Try adding the strtoupper on your action script, or if you want to ensure the value is upper cased from anywhere, add a sql [UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) string function to the field via your query construct.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but how can I trace which one is the action script in Magento? Can you give a hint on how the codes is like so I can try from there.

Comment: Check the source code for the `<form` tag, and see what it says for "action=someScript.php"

Comment: hi i have tried that but it still doesn't work, i think because i don't have sufficient knowledge in php. This is my sample code        '<?php @$_REQUEST['firstname'] = strtoupper(@$_REQUEST['firstname']); ?>    
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">'